# Single Header View at top of UICollectionView with multiple sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I understand how to include a header view per section, but how do I go about having a single header view at the top of a UICollectionView with multiple sections? I just want a view that sits on top of the collectionview that scrolls with the collectionview.

I've looked into decoration/supplementary views..but I think I can also just make it a new section with a single cell. What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is "best practice," but I ended up creating a section at the top with a single cell. I looked into supplementary views, but it seemed like those were primarily used as section headers and footers. New section at top with single item worked well for my purposes.